# KendoUI Grid - Is it possible to have an edit button in the top toolbar and popup and editor for the selected row?

Tags: kendo-ui

I have got a grid, and added a Edit button to the top toolbar, and it has the pencil icon.
toolbar: [ "create", "edit", "save", "cancel" ]

However when I select a row and press it, no popup editor appears.  But it does when i press the add button.

How can I do this?

Regards,

codeOwl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought this would be as easy as just adding the edit button, but apparently in the toolbar the edit button doesn't have a behavior.  You can add it by using a toolbar template.  Unless I'm missing something really obvious.  It is terribly late.

http://jsbin.com/abayer/2/

Comment: I can't make sense of the JSBIN linked to. You can't select rows so the EDIT button does nothing and ADD doesn't work

Comment: Thank you so much :)))))))))

Answer (score 1):

try changing the way that you edit data:

```
.Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
or
.Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
or
.Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
```